# Customize ZSH history search in vi mode

Tags: zsh, command-history, vi-mode

I want to replace default history search widget in vi mode with my own (binding it the the default key, i.e. `/` in command mode).

Here's what I tried putting in my `.zshrc`:

```
custom_command() {
  history | cat  # instead of cat, there will be some custom logic
}
zle -N custom_command
bindkey -M vicmd '/' custom_command
bindkey -M vicmd '^R' custom_command
```

With these bindings, pressing `ctrl-R` does what I expect (displays history list), but hitting `/` doesn't have any effect (I get the default history widget, not my `custom_command`).

Comment: I just tried copy-pasting your code and it works for me. Maybe you have some keybinding setting later in your zshrc? E.g. calling `bindkey -v` for vi mode later will overwrite your binding.